# How to update a string or string array in java from a editttext activity

Tags: java, arrays, xml, string, android-edittext

How do I avoid hard coding a number/string in my java code. Example below the
String/ phoneNumber?.

```
getApplication().startActivity( );

                String phoneNumber = " 1234567890 ";
                String message = " ";
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the title, I assume you're trying to pull the phone number value out from an EditText.

Java:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
String phoneNumber = editText.getText().toString();
```

XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"/>
```

Comment: Yes that is what I need

Comment: I do not know much about preference  activities but I think that the user would lose the number when the applications closes. So a preference activity would also be needed?

Comment: Why not simple file IO to save phone numbers in a .txt or .dat file?

Comment: Thank! you Sir for help.I

Comment: I am a new to development  and this area of editext to a java file is new to me. I do not no how to do that. I created one preference activity in another app to start on boot and that is about it. Is the IO method easier and fits better for what I am trying to do or go the Preference route.

Comment: Either one will work perfectly. IO is simply used to store data for long / semi-long periods of time. For example, if you were developing a game, you would want to use file IO to store info such as current game progress so that this data is not lost upon activity destruction. In other words, if you wanted this app to store several contacts for long periods of time, I would lean towards file IO. However, as I said, both will work fine in your situation.

Comment: I thank you for kindness and help in pointing me in the right direction. I will look for a example of IO and try to employe the method you mentioned tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks to you@ Nerdizzl, Accepted and correct answer. I found a example of IO and text file works well. Problem has been solved.    Thanks again for help.    Mike